# How to create a pop up message "may not work in internet explorer"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, popup

I'm not sure if this has ever been done. Is there a way to create pop-up message, possibly jQuery, that appears at your website that says, "Notice! This website may not work in versions of Internet Explorer.  We recommend using Firefox, Google Chrome, Opera, etc. Sorry for the inconvenience!"

Better yet!  Is it possible to have this notice pop up ONLY when the user opens the website in Internet Explorer?

I wouldn't even know where to begin with a project like this!
Help very much appreciated!!

Comment: This is configured for IE6, but you can use the same methods for your application. http://www.ie6nomore.com/code-samples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1)
    alert("Notice! This website etc.");
</script>
```

Should do the trick. But I think it is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: http://jsfiddle.net/meub/6TsnP/

HTML:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .unsupported-browser {display:block;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<div class="unsupported-browser">
    <div class="container">
         <h2>Please note that this site doesn't support Internet Explorer.</h2>

        <p>We recommend using <a href="https://chrome.google.com">Google Chrome</a> or <a href="https://mozilla.org/firefox/">Firefox</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.unsupported-browser {
    /* Uncomment this for production use
    display:none;*/
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #211E14;
    background-color: #FAE692;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B3A569;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    padding:40px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Place your pop-up code in "yourscript.js" file and write the above on your HTML code to load the external file ONLY if the page is viewed in IE. (you could place an inline script of course inside the conditional statement, but I find it fair enough that IE users should wait some extra milliseconds for the external load request XD - am I mean ? )

Edit: I hate IE !